# Google Chrome does not attach Cookies for CORS request?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, same-origin-policy, google-contacts-api, samesite

I am trying to make a CORS request with credentials(Cookies attached) and Chrome is not attaching the Cookie to my request. I have set the cookie to a sub-domain of the existing page and i could observe it is set successfully from the Cookie manager.

I do not have this problem with Chrome 78th version(latest version). But for the previous versions, I have this problem(I have checked 75 and 77). As well as i do not have any problem with other major browsers also. They also attach cookies without a problem.(I have tested my code with Firefox, IE, Opera and Edge)

This how I have set the Cookie from external service end.

`res.setHeader('Set-Cookie','cdn-token=exp3header_same-site-none; domain=.local.com; path=/; SameSite=None;');`

Complete sample code base can be found in following links:

External service - https://github.com/bhanukayapa/cors-backend.git

Front-end application - https://github.com/bhanukayapa/cors-angular-frontend.git

Can someone please explain the **root cause for this problem**? I checked Chrome release notes also. I could not find and bug fix or improvement related to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the code you're using to make the request or even better, link to a page that demonstrates this issue. Are you testing over HTTPS?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rowan_m . Unfortunately I'll provide the code segment you request and Github repository of a simple application demonstarting this issue. And yes, I am using HTTPS.

Comment: @rowan_m I have updated my question with the requested information. Can you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

If setting `SameSite=None` this must be paired with `Secure`. e.g.

```js
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie','cdn-token=exp3header_same-site-none; domain=.local.com; path=/; SameSite=None; Secure');
```

Comment: Still it's possible right? As per this links => https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032 it says that restriction will be only there after Chrome version 80. Anyway I in my real code I have added Secure flag also. Still not working. Any more suggestions @rowan_m ?Anyway thanks for the reply.